# Make TF2 connect to a particular server when launched from command line

Tags: team-fortress-2

I need some help with starting TF2 using the command prompt and having it connect to a server. Something like the external protocol request when you click "Join Game" on the Steam community website.

I know how to start TF2 from the command prompt, but how do I have it connect to a server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To launch TF2 via command prompt and have it connect to a particular server, you need to add `+connect ip:port` to your command after the path to the executable. You can replace the path to the game's executable with a path to Steam's executable followed by `-applaunch 440`.

Comment: It works! Thank you. 
Is there a way I can have steam display the Game Info instead of connecting automatically? Just incase the server is full.

Comment: @Justin no idea.